# Converting xml DOMDocument to HTML string and echo

Tags: php, html, parsing, domdocument

I have this Class

```
Class Parser extends DOMDocument {

    public function setHTML($file) {
        $this->loadHTMLFile($file);
    }

    public function setAttribute($name, $value) {
        return $this->setAttribute($name, $value);
    }

    public function findById($id) {
        return $this->getElementById($id);
    }

}
```

and I use it like this:

```
$parser = new Parser();
$parser->setHTML('as.html');
$parser->findById("xaxa")->setAttribute('name1', 'value1');
```

but if I have to see the changed HTML I call SAVEHTML like this

```
echo $parser->saveHTML();
```

Is there a way to make it automatic? Like when method setAttribute is called to make

```
$this->saveHTML()
```

auto so I will have this

```
$html =$parser->findById("xaxa")->setAttribute('name1', 'value1');
```

then call

```
echo $html;
```

Thanks alot

Comment: your function saveHTML() where is declared in wich class or file?

Comment: In DOMDocument Class ufc.

Comment: In your class you're already calling parent class's functions from with yours...

Comment: I know how it will work but i don't want it that way. Everytime i should make $html = $parser->saveHTML(); echo $html; and again and again i just want $parser->SaveHTML() to be called auto... thats all

Comment: if my solution fixes your problem, please accept it as as correct answer - so when others encounter your OP know how to solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the DOM object cannot be used (directly) as string, and when you'll try for example echo it will throw an exception

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class DOMDocument could not be converted to string in ...
```

The saveHTML method is explicitly designed to return the nodes as HTML string - than you can echo it. Bear in mind, that actually the nodes are already **updated** (**saved**!) after you call the setAttribute method - the saveHTML is just for **rendering** a html string from the nodes.

Providing I understand your concept, and you still think you want it your way, maybe you can try the below solution - but just for the record, I didnt test the code.

```
Class Parser extends DOMDocument 
{

    public function setHTML($file) 
    {
    $this->loadHTMLFile($file);
    }

    public function setAttribute($name, $value) 
    {
        return $this->setAttribute($name, $value);
    }

    public function findById($id) 
    {
        return $this->getElementById($id);
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->saveHTML(); 
    }
}

// and now this should work

$parser = new Parser();
$parser->setHTML('as.html');
$parser->findById("xaxa")->setAttribute('name1', 'value1');
echo $parser;
```